# What is the difference between find({}, {sort: ...}) and find().sort(...)?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

In MongoDB documentation, when I search for sort, it direct me to the [cursor.sort() page](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.sort/). (btw the documentation doesn't specify what is returned out of this method.). So I used it in my meteor script `Collection.find().sort('date':1)`, but got complained that find().sort is not a function. (I thought `find()` does returns a cursor, isn't it?)

So I did some further search, and found some tutorials tell me to use find({}, {sort: ...}).

So what is the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Meteor framework, some things you need to do the Meteor way!
Just use `Collection.find` as specified in the [Meteor Docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find), and pass a [Sort Specifier](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#sortspecifiers).

What is the difference between the two?
One has been wrapped by Meteor, and works inside the framework, the other one doesn't!

I don't believe you will see any performance difference between 'the Meteor api' from in the framework, or 'the standard MongoDB api' from (non meteor) nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

Using find({}, sort...  Asks Mongo to do the sorting,  and this is the most efficient way because the database server can optimise  a sort if a field is indexed.

Meteor doesn't provide the full Mongo api,  because mini Mongo in the browser does have all the features and they want to provide a consistent api in both client and server.

I haven't checked it but I think if you add a fetch () in between the find and the sort it will work because fetch will return an array which is sortable

Comment: fetch() would change the cursor into an array, which would break some other things in my scripts...

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a bind, because I guess Meteor doesn't support sorting a cursor :)